# Uniqueness of Helmholtz decomposition

Tags: multivariable-calculus, physics

Helmholtz theorem states that given a smooth vector field $\mathbf{H}$, there are a scalar field $\phi$ and a vector field $\mathbf{G}$ such that

$\mathbf{H}=\nabla \phi +\nabla \times \mathbf{G}$

and

$\nabla \mathbf{\cdot G}=0$

Is this decomposition unique? That is, given $\mathbf{H}$, are the fields $\phi$, $\mathbf{G}$ satisfying the above equations unique?

Edit: Unique, up to an additive constant.

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean "unique up to an additive constant"? (A latex-suggestion, use \mathbf{G} $\mathbf{G}$ instead of "poor man's bold" \pmb{G} $\pmb{G}$ which looks ugly if you do something wrong like $\pmb{\cdot G}$)

Comment: @Myself: Yes, unique up to an additive constant. Edited my post to correct that.

Comment: Look here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Helmholtz_decomposition

Comment: @Alexandr What's the problem? The Helmholtz/Hodge decompositions only make sense when you have a Riemannian metric anyway, and in the Helmholtz type statement, like most statements in classical vector calculus, the Euclidean metric is implicitly used to identify vectors and covectors.

Comment: cross-post: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/10522/3064

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The decomposition is not unique without further conditions. You can add linear terms to $\phi$ and $\mathbf G$ that yield constant contributions to $\mathbf H$ that cancel:

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
\phi
&\to&
\phi + z\;,
\\
\nabla\phi
&\to&
\nabla\phi + \mathbf e_z\;,
\\
\mathbf G
&\to&
\mathbf G + \frac{1}{2}(y\mathbf e_x-x\mathbf e_y)\;,
\\
\nabla\times\mathbf G
&\to&
\nabla\times\mathbf G - \mathbf e_z\;.
\end{eqnarray}
$$

However, I think that if you impose suitable conditions that the fields decay at infinity, the decomposition should be unique.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I realize now that boundary conditions are essential. After boundary conditions have been specified, the resolution is unique.