# Vector field with skew-symmetric Jacobian matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, dynamical-systems

Consider a vector field $X\in\mathfrak{X}(\mathbb{R}^n)$, and suppose to know that $JX(x) = \frac{\partial X(x)}{\partial x}\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is symmetric for every $x$. Then it is well-known that there exists a potential function $I:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that $\nabla I(x) = X(x)$.

I was wondering if a similar characterization of vector fields with a skew-symmetric jacobian matrix exists. Is there a generic form they must have on a simply-connected space like $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Playing around, I was thinking that one can proceed by decomposing the Jacobian matrix of a generic vector field in its symmetric and skew-symmetric part, to get
$$
JX(x) = \nabla^2 I(x) + \frac{JX(x)-JX(x)^T}{2}
$$
for some $I$. Now, is the skew-symmetric part relatable to the jacobian of a specifically structured vector field?

Another way to deal with the problem is through the analysis of the sensitivity matrix of the associated dynamical system, since defining
$$
S(x(t)) = \frac{\partial x(t)}{\partial x_0}
$$
one would get
$$
\dot{x}(t) = X(x(t)),\quad x(0)=x_0
$$
$$
\dot{S}(t) = JX(x(t))S(t),\quad S(0)=I.
$$
Thus a vector field $X$ is with skew-symmetric Jacobian if and only if its sensitivity matrix is orthogonal for every time. However I can not move forward, since I do not find classes of vector fields with this property.

Answer (score 1):

In $\mathbb R^3$ the answer is quite simple when one knows where to look.

- A vector field that has an anti symmetric Jacobian is in the case of flat $\mathbb R^3$ nothing else than a Killing vector field that characterizes isometries of the metric $ds^2=dx^2+dy^2+dz^2\,.$ These isometries form the Lie group $ISO(3)$ which consists of translations and rotations. Therefore, the Killing vector fields are the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{iso}(3)$ of that group. That Lie algebra is six dimensional and is generated by
  $$
  \underbrace{\partial_x\,,\partial_y\,,\partial_z\,,}_{3\;\text{translations}}\,\quad
  \underbrace{y\,\partial_x-x\,\partial_y\,,-z\,\partial_x+x\,\partial_z\,,z\,\partial_y-y\,\partial_z\,.}_{3\;\text{rotations}}
  $$
  The vector fields $X$ with anti-symmetric Jacobian are precisely the
  linear combinations (with constant coefficients) of these six generating Killing vector fields.

***Old version (outdated)***

Sorry for repeating known stuff but I find your question interesting and want
to put it into some context:

- In $\mathbb R^3$ the symmetry of the Jacobi matrix of $X$ is equivalent to
  $X$ being rotation free: $\nabla\times X\equiv 0\,.$ This is equivalent to the existence of a potential function $\Phi:\mathbb R^3\to\mathbb R$ such that $X=\nabla \Phi\,.$
- A vector field that is divergence free, $\nabla\cdot X\equiv 0\,,$ can be expressed as the rotation of a vector field $Y\,:$ $X=\nabla\times Y\,.$
- By the [Helmholtz decomposition theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmholtz_decomposition) any (smooth enough) vector field $X$ can be additively decomposed into a component that is rotation free and a component that is divergence free. Then the first to bullet points apply:
  $$
  X=\nabla \Phi+\nabla\times Y\,.
  $$
- Assuming $X=\nabla \times Y$ the Jacobi matrix of $X$ is
  $$
  \begin{pmatrix}\partial_1\partial_2Y_3-\partial_1\partial_3Y_2&\partial_2\partial_2Y_3-\partial_2\partial_3Y_2 &\partial_3\partial_2Y_3-\partial_3\partial_3Y_2\\[2mm]
  \partial_1\partial_3Y_1-\partial_1\partial_1Y_3&\partial_2\partial_3Y_1-\partial_2\partial_1Y_3&\partial_3\partial_3Y_1-\partial_3\partial_1Y_3\\[2mm]
  \partial_1\partial_1Y_2-\partial_1\partial_2Y_1&\partial_2\partial_1Y_2-\partial_2\partial_2Y_1&\partial_3\partial_1Y_2-\partial_3\partial_2Y_1&\end{pmatrix}\,.\tag{1}
  $$
  This is in general not anti-symmetric.
- If we subtract from $X$ the component that has a symmetric Jacobi matrix (is rotation free) then, by the Helmholtz theorem, we must obtain a component that is
  divergence free and therefore have a Jacobi matrix of the form (1) which is not anti symmetric in general.
- If the Jacobi matrix of $X$ *is* anti-symmetric then its diagonal elements $\partial_iX_i$ must all vanish identically. In particular, their sum (divergence of $X$) must vanish. This means that anti-symmetry of the Jacobi matrix is a stronger condition than divergence freeness. Anti-symmetry implies the existence of $Y$ but is not necessary for it.
- Typical examples of vector fields $X$ that have anti-symmetric Jacobian are the three divergence free fields
  $$
  \pmatrix{y\\-x\\0}\,,\quad \pmatrix{-z\\0\\x}\,,\quad \pmatrix{0\\z\\-y}\,.
  $$
  As Helmholtz decompositons one can choose $\Phi\equiv 0$ and $Y$ being
  the corresponding one of
  $$
  \frac12\pmatrix{0\\0\\x^2+y^2}\,,\quad \frac12\pmatrix{0\\x^2+z^2\\0}\,,\quad \frac12\pmatrix{y^2+z^2\\0\\0}\,.
  $$
  This is however [not a unique](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/41857/949989) decomposition.